# var dump is printing entire script tag in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have checked windows width in php and store it in variable. While putting the variable under the if condition, it is always showing me false. I did var_dump and i can see the entire script to be printed.

```
$window_width = "<script type='text/javascript'>document.write(window.innerWidth);</script>";
```

This is in the controller, which i pass to the view.

```
var_dump($pageWidth); 
//ctrl+u is showing this
//string(74) "<script type='text/javascript'>document.write(window.innerWidth);
//Html is rendering, so it is showing string(74) "768"
```

Comment: Why would the server need to know the client's window width? And `$window_width` is not `$pageWidth`

Comment: and what is the problem?

Comment: I just want value out of this.. it is giving me entire script tag

Comment: You can't. Please read carefully some answers in the dup linked on the top of the question.